# Add custom e-mail variable

Tags: magento-2.1, invoice, email-templates

I added attribute to invoice using \Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory->addAttribute.

Now i need to show that attribute in invoice_new e-mail. Is there a way to programmatically add that variable to e-mail? Ideally to be show in Insert variable "window" .

Comment: In which table have you create entry of your custom attribute?

Comment: \Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory->addAttribute does it automatically in it's own table. It's in InstallData.

Comment: entry are created in sales_invoice table?

Comment: @Rakesh - Yes in sales_invoice